# Locate the javascript source code from a function using CHrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Goal:
Retrieve the javascript of the function that you can zoom in and zoom out from this [webpage](https://www.quora.com/What-does-a-programmers-screen-look-like).

Problem:
I can't find the source code. Where can I find it by using chrome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monitor the event listeners on DOM elements using the **Elements** tab of the Chrome DevTools; see [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events#view_event_listeners_registered_on_dom_elements).

Simply select your element of interest (say, an image) in the DOM tree, and display its event listeners. You can then narrow them down to `click`, `mousedown`, `mouseup` or whatever. Expand these events, and you'll see the JavaScript files that attached listeners on them. You may find what you seek there.

Before we part ways: if the JavaScript code is *minified* (a huge one-liner, unreadable file), don't forget that Chrome can [*pretty print*](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/pretty-print) it (to a certain degree) by clicking on the `{}` just on the bottom-left corner of the code panel.

Comment: Thank you for your help!